# How do you separate a column where values are separated by commas r

Tags: r, air, data-conversion, weather

I am using R and I have a set of weather readings in four columns which are separated by commas as below:

```
  pollutant air_quality_idx    air_quality_cat air_quality_cat_idx
  PM2.5,PM10,OZONE         28,6,24     Good,Good,Good               1,1,1
  PM2.5,PM10,OZONE         28,5,25     Good,Good,Good               1,1,1
  OZONE,PM2.5,PM10         26,23,4     Good,Good,Good               1,1,1
  OZONE,PM2.5,PM10         26,23,3     Good,Good,Good               1,1,1
  OZONE,PM2.5,PM10         27,22,3     Good,Good,Good               1,1,1
  OZONE,PM2.5,PM10         27,24,2     Good,Good,Good               1,1,1
  PM2.5,PM10,OZONE         50,4,27     Good,Good,Good               1,1,1
  PM2.5,PM10,OZONE         54,4,22 Moderate,Good,Good               2,1,1
  PM2.5,PM10,OZONE         56,5,22 Moderate,Good,Good               2,1,1
  PM2.5,PM10,OZONE         60,5,28 Moderate,Good,Good               2,1,1
```

The order of the three readings (Ozone, 10 micron, 2.5 micron) shifts randomly.  I would like to break the 4 columns with 3 values separated by commas into 12 columns and group them together so the first value in the four columns will be together, the second values together, and the third values together for each row.  Does anyone have any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Which programming language/environment are you using or want to use?

Comment: Sorry I am using R

Comment: Sorry I'm not an R developer.  I've added the r tag to the question.

Answer (score 1):

My "splitstackshape" package is perfect for this kind of transformation:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(mydf, names(mydf), direction = "long")
#     pollutant air_quality_idx air_quality_cat air_quality_cat_idx
#  1:     PM2.5              28            Good                   1
#  2:      PM10               6            Good                   1
#  3:     OZONE              24            Good                   1
#  4:     PM2.5              28            Good                   1
#  5:      PM10               5            Good                   1
# ---                                                              
# 26:      PM10               5            Good                   1
# 27:     OZONE              22            Good                   1
# 28:     PM2.5              60        Moderate                   2
# 29:      PM10               5            Good                   1
# 30:     OZONE              28            Good                   1
```

In base R, you can also do:

```
data.frame(lapply(mydf, function(x) 
  type.convert(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), ",", TRUE)))))
```

Or, with the "tidyverse", you can try:

```
library(tidyverse)
mydf %>%
  mutate_all(funs(strsplit(as.character(.), ","))) %>%
  unnest()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution, though possibly not the most elegant. It relies on using `tidyr::separate` to split each column into three, and then simply splits that 12-column table into three 4-column tables with `dplyr::select`, gives them the same column names, and stacks them on top of each other with `bind_rows`.

```
library(tidyverse)
tbl <- read_table2(
  "pollutant air_quality_idx    air_quality_cat air_quality_cat_idx
  PM2.5,PM10,OZONE         28,6,24     Good,Good,Good               1,1,1
  PM2.5,PM10,OZONE         28,5,25     Good,Good,Good               1,1,1
  OZONE,PM2.5,PM10         26,23,4     Good,Good,Good               1,1,1
  OZONE,PM2.5,PM10         26,23,3     Good,Good,Good               1,1,1
  OZONE,PM2.5,PM10         27,22,3     Good,Good,Good               1,1,1
  OZONE,PM2.5,PM10         27,24,2     Good,Good,Good               1,1,1
  PM2.5,PM10,OZONE         50,4,27     Good,Good,Good               1,1,1
  PM2.5,PM10,OZONE         54,4,22 Moderate,Good,Good               2,1,1
  PM2.5,PM10,OZONE         56,5,22 Moderate,Good,Good               2,1,1
  PM2.5,PM10,OZONE         60,5,28 Moderate,Good,Good               2,1,1",
  col_types = "cccc"
)

separated <- tbl %>%
  separate(pollutant, c("pol1", "pol2", "pol3"), sep = ",") %>%
  separate(air_quality_idx, c("aqi1", "aqi2", "aqi3"), sep = ",") %>%
  separate(air_quality_cat, c("aqc1", "aqc2", "aqc3"), sep = ",") %>%
  separate(air_quality_cat_idx, c("aci1", "aci2", "aci3"), sep = ",")

output <- bind_rows(
  separated %>%
    select(ends_with("1")) %>%
    set_names(c("pol", "aqi", "aqc", "aci")),
  separated %>%
    select(ends_with("2")) %>% 
    set_names(c("pol", "aqi", "aqc", "aci")),
  separated %>%
    select(ends_with("3")) %>%
    set_names(c("pol", "aqi", "aqc", "aci"))
)
# A tibble: 30 x 4
   pollution aq_idx aq_cat   aq_cat_idx
   <chr>     <chr>  <chr>    <chr>     
 1 PM2.5     28     Good     1         
 2 PM2.5     28     Good     1         
 3 OZONE     26     Good     1         
 4 OZONE     26     Good     1         
 5 OZONE     27     Good     1         
 6 OZONE     27     Good     1         
 7 PM2.5     50     Good     1         
 8 PM2.5     54     Moderate 2         
 9 PM2.5     56     Moderate 2         
10 PM2.5     60     Moderate 2         
# ... with 20 more rows
```